# Javascript shorthand boolean type

Tags: javascript, boolean, shorthand

Sorry if this question is seems old, but curious the answer. 
so I have the following snippet

```js
function halo(firstname, lastname) {
  lastname = lastname || 'no last name';
  console.log(firstname + ' ' + lastname);
}

function testbol(start) {
  start = start || true;
  console.log(start);
}

halo('jee');
halo('jee', 'tan');
    
testbol();
testbol(false);
```

the question is: why the second `testbool` function produce `true` while it should `false`

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) what `||` returns. If `start` is false, `start || true` is `true`

Comment: because false is false....

Answer (score 2):

`left || right` evaluates as the left hand side if the left hand side is a true value, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

`false || true` evaluates as the right hand side, which is `true`.

In short: You are testing for *truthfulness* not *definedness* which would be:

```js
testdefined();
testdefined(false);

function testdefined(start){
    start = typeof start === "undefined" ? true : start; ;
    console.log(start);
}
```

Comment: You went into insane lengths to make the thing even more confusing.  Why do you see things with left hand side and right hand side, this isnt math operations were doing with multiplication division and substraction. The rule is simple, anything false in an AND statement results to false, anything true in an OR statement makes the statement true. simple.

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna — No. `3 || 5` is `3` not `true`.

Comment: are those booleans ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement evaluates **false || true** which evaluates to true.

Answer (score -1):

"False or true" is true. Consider the sentence "the sky is red or the sky is blue" -- is it true or false?

Comment: Its neither - it's just a statement.

Comment: We're not in philosophy class; I'm not going to go to "consider the proposition denoted by the sentence 'the sky is red or the sky is blue'" levels of nuance to demonstrate what is a *more* fundamental concept. :)

Comment: "The sky is red or the sky is blue - how does that make you feel?" :)